# Why am I getting a 500 error upon uploading photo with correct model and controller information?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, model

I'm not sure why I'm getting a 500 error when trying to make a file upload that's associates with the uploaded file to the current user that's logged in.  I've tried too many ways to jot down here.  I'm suspecting the `'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName()` line but I'm not entirely sure.

My intention is to store the `file_path` information to the database along with the the user `id`.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request, Photo $photo) {
    $uploadedPhoto = $request->user()->photos()->create([
        'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName()
    ]);

    return response()->json($photo->with('user')->find($uploadedPhoto->id));
}
```

Here's photo model:

```
class Photo extends Model {
protected $fillable = ['file_path'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

Here's the User model:

```
public function photos() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

Here's my migration table:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('file_path', 140);
        $table->integer('likes_amount')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign("id")->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: without returning json response, does it save in database ? because for `file_path` you have to save a file in your storage and then save that path to your database.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir no it doesn't

Comment: Do this before create method `$path = $request->file('fileToUpload')->store('images');` and then inside create method do this `'file_path' => $path` and in response just return a simple message like `return "success";` for checking

Comment: @AkhtarMunir still getting 500 error :(

Comment: you want to pass the currently logged in user_id as well to photo table ? and when you `dd($request->file('fileToUpload'));` what it shows ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like This In your controller:(Follow the step and change the code as your need )

```
public function upload(Request $request, Photo $photo) {
    $data = $request->image; // image
    $destinationPath = 'images/'; // upload path
    $profilefile = $name . '.' . $data->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $data->move($destinationPath, $profilefile); //storing to folder the file
    return $profilefile;
}
```